# Android: how define android:layout_span for height

Tags: android, android-layout

Suppose there are two Button in TableLayout and if I mention android:layout_span="1" in both the button then the complete width is divided into two part and each button sit into one part.
Can we achieve this same thing for height.
In my application four button is there which arranged in linear order one on the top of other.
I want all these four button cover complete height of the screen in any size of screen.
My Problem is here if I launch this screen on one device then it look like:-

[image]

But if I launch this layout on big screen then it looks like:-

How on all the screen the button cover(uniformly distribute)?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the layout height for each view to be 0 and instead use layout weight. Use the value 1 for layout weight for all the buttons for them to be equally spaced!